# Restrict property type

Tags: interface, properties, implements

Good day,

I have a class which represents a collection. The collection has a property of type `Type` which allows you to specify the data type of each element's meta data object. Each time an element is added to the collection a new instance of the assigned meta data object is created with `Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)` from within the collection class.

What I need is to restrict the meta data object's type to a type that implements a specific intreface. Example:

```
publlic class Collection
{
    public Type MetaDataType;

    // other code
}

public class CollectionImplementation
{
    // some properties

    public CollectionImplementation()
    {
        Collection c = new Collection();

        // valid assignment
        c.MetaDataType = typeof(ValidMetaClass);

        // invalid assignement
        c.MetaDataType = typeof(InvalidMetaClass);
    }

    // some functions
}

public class ValidMetaClass : IMetaInterface
{
    // valid meta class code
}

public class InvalidMetaClass
{
    // invalid meta class code
}

public interface IMetaInterface
{
    // interface code
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Thank you in advance to any and all contributors; I appreciate any and all input.

Kind regards,
me

Comment: it's C# - I saw that my CollectionImplementation class constructor signature was erroneous so I fixed (I'm not sure if this is why you're asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using generics and type constraints on your constructor instead of setting the public field MetaDataType in your Collection class.

```
public CollectionImplementation<T>(T MetaDataType) where T : NameOfInterface
{
}
```

Comment: seeing as you and Nabheet provided similar solutions, please see my comment to his post, in stead of replying to both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use restrictions on generic types.

```
public class Collection<T> where T : IMetaInterface
{
T MetaDataType;
}
```

Or you could just throw an exception when adding elements like:

```
if( !( addedElement is IMetaInterface )) throw new Exception("Please don't do this");
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to assist. i'm not very familiar with generic types yet. i have used other classes using generics, but never my own.

my classes use a couple of custom events, delegates and other private functions and it seems that using generics requires that the generic types permeate my entire solution as types are passed as parameters and otherwise referenced.

not a problem as this is something new and interesting for me, but if that is the case I'll need to some research on generic types and I'm not going to bother you guys about it just yet ^^,

thanx